# How to do something in jquery droppable event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

Hi all sorry if its a silly question.But I am new to javascript.

I have a div on which is draggable.Now I want to do some thing when that div is dropped
So far I have write a simple alert but its not working.
Can any one guide me how do I write some code in drop event.

Here is my code

```
<div id = "par" class = "ui-draggable" style="position: relative; height: 200px; width: 200px;outline:2px solid green">
</div>

<script>
     $('#par').draggable();
     $('#par').droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  alert("blabla");                                       
            }
     });
</script>
```

Here is link to fiddle
[Draggable droppable](http://jsfiddle.net/MddyD/1/)

Comment: `.droppable()` is for what you want to be able to drop things on, not for what gets dropped.  You'll need to make another element so you have something to drop your div onto

Comment: Thanks @MrOBrian but I want an event which occur when the element I am dragging is dropped.I there any event like this

Comment: I think you might just need the `stop` event of draggable then, unless you are dropping the element onto something specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like MrObrian says, you need to be using `draggable.stop` for what you are tying to achieve.

This fiddle illustrates the difference.
http://jsfiddle.net/MddyD/4/

```
$(function() {
 $('#par').draggable({
               stop: function() { 
                       alert("hi");
                     }
            });

 $("#dropIn").droppable({
               drop: function() { 
                       alert("drop");
                     }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Droppable.drop to catch what was dropped on droppable(You need to use both draggable and droppable)

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-drop

```
<script>
     $('#thingToDrag").draggable();
     $('#par').droppable({
            accept: "#thingToDrag",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  alert("draggable dropped");                                       
            }
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `dragstop` event which will be launched when the draggable element will stop being dragged :

```
$('#par')
.draggable()
.on('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
    alert('ok')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MddyD/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to work with the object you setup as draggable. You can bind a function to the stop event.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#par').draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                alert("Dropped");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the $(function(){ }); just tells the script to run when the document is done loading. You could also just bind any other function that you create to the stop event.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop